# Python + SVN access in Linux, using PySvn

Tags: linux, python, svn, pycharm

I have Python 3.3 and Subversion running in an old Fedora 20 (I know) Virtual Machine on a Windows host.

This is work related and I am not allowed to use different versions of anything :-(

I would like to access SVN using [the PySvn module](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_guide.html).

I managed to installing it using `sudo dnf install pysvn`, but found it installed in `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/` by default.

I copied the relevant `pysvn/_pysvn.so` to `/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/`, but when I run a script which only `import pysvn`, I get

```
import pysvn
ImportError: No module named 'pysvn'
```

Any idea how I get things working?

There is a strong preference to use the Linux VM, but I *could* possibly persuade them to let me use Windows, except that I don't have & cant get admin rights to allow me to run the .exe to install pysvn.

Is there any way to download and copy the appropriate modules and get it working in preferably Linux, failing that, Windows?

I am using the PyCharm IDE, but don't see any way to set the search path for imports to where pysvn is installed.

Comment: You can try download the source code here and use the setup.py to install it for your python 3: https://pysvn.sourceforge.io/downloads.html

Comment: Please post that as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download the source code from here:

https://pysvn.sourceforge.io/downloads.html

and use the `setup.py` to install it for your python 3.